# Can't capture and echo PID by $!

Tags: bash, unix, tcpdump, nohup

I am trying to start tcpdump as a background process, and get its PID. The script will monitor the system for disk space, cpu and memory, and kill the tcpdump process if any goes beyond the threshold. But I cant get the PID using $!. The output is blank.

```
#!/bin/bash
`nohup tcpdump port 389 -i bond0 -s 0 -w /tmp/capture.pcap  > nohup2.out 2>&1&`
my_pid=$!                                                                      
echo $my_pid                                                                   

flag=1                                                                         
exit 1
```

and the output is

```
bash # sh t.sh

bash #
```

Comment: remove the backticks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
`nohup tcpdump port 389 -i bond0 -s 0 -w /tmp/capture.pcap  > nohup2.out 2>&1&`
```

to this:

```
nohup tcpdump port 389 -i bond0 -s 0 -w /tmp/capture.pcap  > nohup2.out 2>&1 &
```

The backticks mean that the command should be run in a subshell and its output captured and substituted into a new command. For example, this command:

```
`echo foo bar`
```

is equivalent to this command:

```
foo bar
```

because it runs `echo foo bar`, captures the output `foo bar`, and then runs `foo bar`. In your case you have absolutely no need of that (if only because you're redirecting the output to a file), so you can just drop them.